# Java: Get URI from FilePath

Tags: java, url, uri, filepath

I've little knowledge of Java. I need to construct a string representation of an URI from `FilePath(String)` on windows. Sometimes the `inputFilePath` I get is: `file:/C:/a.txt` and sometimes it is: `C:/a.txt`. Right now, what I'm doing is:

```
new File(inputFilePath).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()
```

The above works fine for paths, which are not prefixed with `file:/`, but for paths prefixed with `file:/`, the .`toURI` method is converting it to a invalid URI, by appending value of current dir, and hence the path becomes invalid.

Please help me out by suggesting a correct way to get the proper URI for both kind of paths.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to just remove `file:/` from the start of the string if present? Or might there be other valid prefixes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are the valid file uri:

```
file:/C:/a.txt            <- On Windows
file:///C:/a.txt          <- On Windows
file:///home/user/a.txt   <- On Linux
```

So you will need to remove `file:/` or `file:///` for Windows and `file://` for Linux.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `Normalize();`

Example:

```
path = Paths.get("/", input).normalize();
```

this one line will **normalize** all your paths.

Comment: Which is better - 1. new File(inputFilePath).toURI() or 2. Paths.get(inputFilePath).toUri() ?

Comment: @gaurav in this case Paths.get() will provide a similar results but because we will not have to create a `FIle` object the second option might be better.

Answer (score 5):

From SAXLocalNameCount.java from https://jaxp.java.net:

```
/**
 * Convert from a filename to a file URL.
 */
private static String convertToFileURL ( String filename )
{
    // On JDK 1.2 and later, simplify this to:
    // "path = file.toURL().toString()".
    String path = new File ( filename ).getAbsolutePath ();
    if ( File.separatorChar != '/' )
    {
        path = path.replace ( File.separatorChar, '/' );
    }
    if ( !path.startsWith ( "/" ) )
    {
        path = "/" + path;
    }
    String retVal =  "file:" + path;

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: since JavaSE7 does that one line ...  


 `java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( xmlFileAsString ).toAbsolutePath().toUri()`

  
Returns eg. `"file:///C:/develop/doku/projects/Documentry/THB/src/docbkx/Systemvoraussetzungen.xml"`

Comment: @udoline `Paths.get(xmlFileAsString)` is the correct method to use for that. It does the same thing internally.

Comment: @udoline is the .toAbsolutePath() method necessary before the call to .toUri()?

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `new File(String)` is a path, not a URI. The part of your post after 'but' is therefore an invalid use of the API.

Comment: So what should I do convert an URI to path? Essentially, to get a  path which is not prefixed with "file:"

Comment: @user1073005  `new URI(uri).getPath()`, but this is a new question, isn't it? Your question above is about how to 'construct a string representation of an URI'.

Comment: Which is better - 1. new File(inputFilePath).toURI() or 2. Paths.get(inputFilePath).toUri() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String brokenPath = "file:/C:/a.txt";

        System.out.println(brokenPath);

        if (brokenPath.startsWith("file:/")) {
            brokenPath = brokenPath.substring(6,brokenPath.length());
        }
        System.out.println(brokenPath);
    }
}
```

Gives output:

```
file:/C:/a.txt
C:/a.txt
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Apache Commons' `StringUtils.removeStart(...)`:  `brokenPath = StringUtils.removeStart(brokenPath, "file:/")`.