# Refactoring Windows, UNIX, URI path mixture

Tags: java, refactoring

What alternatives are there for refactoring code which stores various types of paths as `String` objects to use only `URI` objects?

The code currently has paths stored as `String` objects where the values can be

- System paths (directory separator of the current platform)
- URIs
- Windows paths (`\` directory separator on all platforms)
- UNIX paths (`/` directory separator on all platforms)
- Chimera paths (`\` directory separator, URL encoding)

The code base has *some* unit tests. The approach I have in mind is

1. Introduce `WindowsFile`, `UnixFile`, and `ChimeraFile` wrapper classes
2. Convert code use `File`, `URI`, or wrapper class instead of `String`
3. Refactor code to only use `URI` by handling each type in turn

Are there other refactoring approaches or steps that would make the process easier or safer.

Comment: It appears to be a valid way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use File.Separator instead of "/" and "\" and is simple and is done without any problems

Comment: Not all paths are generated _in_ code, so I can't just change how they are created. Also, the separator is only part of the problem because I also have to make sure paths are valid `URI`s. The reason I want to convert everything into `URI` is to have type safety, the old `String` approach was the reason why the paths are currently not uniform.

Comment: path1 = "blah"+File.Separator+"blah_blah" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323760/java-get-uri-from-filepath

Comment: The question was about the procedure to refactor various path types in String objects to URI objects, not how to construct paths as Strings or how to get URIs from Strings.

Comment: @jelovirt if is properly contructed, than is easy to refactor

Comment: construction is not the problem. Tt's that the chimera paths are passed and modified around the code.