# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcI$sp(ActivatorCli.sca la:21)

Tags: java, windows, playframework

I am using git bash in windows. I downloaded and unzip the play framework and set the path also, but as soon as I run activator new it gives following error

```
$ activator new
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcI$sp(ActivatorCli.sca
la:21)
        at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:19)
        at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:19)
        at activator.ActivatorCli$.withContextClassloader(ActivatorCli.scala:179
)
        at activator.ActivatorCli$.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:19)
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.run(ActivatorLauncher.scala:28)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: BAD URI: file://f:/Play/activator-1.2.10-
minimal

        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.uriToFilename(ActivatorPrope
rties.java:106)
        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.ACTIVATOR_HOME_FILENAME(Acti
vatorProperties.java:113)
        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.ACTIVATOR_TEMPLATE_LOCAL_REP
O(ActivatorProperties.java:179)
        at activator.UICacheHelper$.<init>(UICacheHelper.scala:31)
        at activator.UICacheHelper$.<clinit>(UICacheHelper.scala)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:397)
        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.uriToFilename(ActivatorPrope
rties.java:101)
        ... 19 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

can any one help how shall i proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much clear if you read your (own) stack trace carefully:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: BAD URI: file://f:/Play/activator-1.2.10-minimal
```

You are trying to access a file via an `URI` which is malformed.

A correct URI would be either `file:/f:/Play/activator-1.2.10-minimal` or `file:///f:/Play/activator-1.2.10-minimal` (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324127)).

Comment: thanks for help Plonus can u tell me how and where can I change the URI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AmitSingh Do I know your code? I don't know where you get the URI from and how you work with this... I suspect you class `activator.properties.ActivatorProperties` will read some properties and somwhere there it could be...

Answer (score 0):

Amit... probably he dont know (how to) "play" ....

check this up...
https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/648