# Java - How to convert a filepath to a Uri

Tags: filepath, file-uri

```
import java.io.File
File myFile;
String filePath = myFile.getPath();
```

How to convert the above filePath variable to a String that follows FileURIScheme ?

Comment: Have you tried to check javadoc? File has toURI method.

Comment: Yes I tried that. But if I give
 File myFile = new File("/home/folder1/a.txt");
System.out.println(myFile.toURI().toString());
It will give the URI as file:/home/folder1/z.txt
But according to FileURI Scheme it should be file:///home/folder1/a.txt

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323760/java-get-uri-from-filepath

Comment: Hm, yes, it seems it's because URI constructed from File lacks host information. Then look at one of constructors of URI class.