# Java Ilegal character in path at index 2

Tags: java, javafx

I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\Emre\Desktop\PN1g1z.gif
```

And I really don't get what's wrong.

This is what throws the exception:

```
   Media media = new Media(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: \ is escaping symbol. There should be C:\\ or C:/ if Media class could parse it. Try to use file.getCanonicalPath()

Comment: You pass a file path to something that awaits an URI.Look at this link for conversion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323760/java-get-uri-from-filepath

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Media` expects an URI as String in the constructor. So, instead of using `File#getAbsolutePath()`, you should be using `File#toURI()` instead.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI%28%29

From the `Media#new` JavaDoc (thanks @Andreas):

> source - The URI of the source media.

Comment: Not just *seems*, it's actually documented in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29): *"The source must represent a valid `URI` and is immutable."*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a big problem where you put your server.

I already faced this problem before. I used Geronimo with the space in my direction `D:\Common DevTool\Geronimo`.

**You have two ways to resolve:**

1. Change to `D:\Tool\Geronimo`. It ran well.
   Your directory is not correct: `C:/Program Files`. You should move your server to another place without the space in the name.
2. Upgrade the JSF version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but another exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\MyUser\project\src\main\packagex\file.csv

The project was created using java not by me. It tried to read a csv file. It worked ok on linux but crashed on windows 10.

My solution was change the absolute path to relative and switch reverse slash to "normal" slash. The url finally worked with this:

src/main/packagex/file.csv

It seems colon and reverse slash triggered the exception. That is the reason exception indicates index 2 because colon is located in second position at url

Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\MyUser...

Reference:
https://background.sysfactory.online/index.php/2022/09/23/solucion-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-illegal-character-in-opaque-part-at-index-2-cusersmyuser/